# Caching issue with LESS.js when used with Initializr

Tags: less, boilerplate, initializer

I am about to start a new project that requires a responsive design solution and I'd also like to take advantage of LESS.js for the styling.

I downloaded the Responsive template from [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) and set it up as a new site on my localhost. I have begun making minor tweaks to the `index.html` file to begin styling the page up as it would be required for my project. I began by adjusting the width of the `.wrapper` class and was frustrated when my changes did not appear to be making any difference when viewing in the browser.

However upon changing the name of the folder containing the files and amending the URL, my changes appear, so there is obviously some sort of caching issue when using LESS on Localhost.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: have you tried compiling to CSS and seeing if that also has same issue? also provide more details in the description about the server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was disabling, or deleting, cookies of the domain on which you're developing.